# Cannot find symbol method - tabbed acivity

Tags: java, android

I want to create a live timer for for tabbed activity.

However, this is the error I get:

> Error:(29, 38) error: cannot find symbol method runOnUniThread()

This is my code:

```
package com.example.Sci.livetimeanddate;

import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class sub_page01 extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Sub_page01";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01,container,false);

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        getActivity().runOnUniThread(new Runnable() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                            public void run() {
                                TextView tdate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
                                long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy\nhh-mm-ss a");
                                String dateString = sdf.format(date);
                                tdate.setText(dateString);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return view;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `runOnUniThread`. There should be `runOnUiThread`